# A question in the proof of a theorem in structure of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I am studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford and I was unable to understand reasoning behind this particular corollary (Corollary 6.3) Page 219.

**Corollary 6.3**. A unitary module $A$ over a principal ideal domain is free if and only if $A$ is projective.

Proof. ($\Rightarrow$) Theorem 3.2. ($\Leftarrow$) There is a short exact sequence $0\to K\xrightarrow{\subset}{F}\xrightarrow{f}{A}\to 0$ ith $F$ free, $f$ an epimorphism and $K=\operatorname{Ker} f$ by Corollary 2.2. If $A$ is projective, then $F\cong K\oplus A$ by Theorem 3.4. Therefore, $A$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $F$, whence $A$ is free by Theorem 6.1. $\blacksquare$

**Corollary 2.2**: Every (unitary) module A over a ring R (with identity) is the homomorphic image of a free R-module F. If A is finitely generated, then F may be chosen finitely generated.

Question: How does unitary module or projective module implies existence of short exact sequence given in image?

I have no help as this was not covered in class.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You don't require  $A $ to be projective to get the short exact sequence. Projectivity is used to get the isomorphism (splitting).

Comment: To address your actual question: Corollary $2.2$ gives us a surjective map $f$ from a free module $F$ to $A$. Verify that $$0\to\ker f\to F\xrightarrow{f}A\to0$$ is exact.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier what is the map that takes ker f to F?

Comment: Inclusion.${}{}{}$